# What is the difference in dine and dinner?

Tags: word-usage

i'm seeing that two word "dine" and "dinner" , my question what is the difference between this word if its mean similar?

example of vacabulary with this word :

```
I am eating dine
```

```
I am eat dinner
```

Comment: Where did you find your examples?

Comment: Have you looked at a dictionary? Any dictionary will tell you that *dine* is a verb.

Comment: StoneyB, he probably doesn't have an English dictionary handy and may not understand English well enough to use an online one that is written for native speakers. We should give these learners the benefit of the doubt. That's what this site is for and that's what we're here for.

Comment: @ThePhoton  are example that I create , why ?

Comment: @StoneyB yes I looked at a dictionary

Comment: Well, now you have the answer to your question.

Comment: @Nick: ELL has a close reason for dictionary lookups, because it's assumed that learners will have a dictionary of some kind available as a basic part of their studies. (And there are numerous online learner's dictionaries.) It's not useful for us to simply reiterate what a basic dictionary will say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, both of your examples are written incorrectly. They should be written this way:

> I am eating **dinner**. (rather than **dine**)
>
> I am **eating** dinner. (rather than **eat**)

Second, "dine" is the verb whereas "dinner" is the noun.  Notice how "dine" is used in the following examples:

> I **dine** with my parents every night.
>
> We **dine** at Cafe Tandoor every Tuesday.
>
> We are going to The Winking Lizard **to dine**.

Notice how "dinner" is used in the following examples:

> I have **dinner** with my parents every night.
>
> We have **dinner** at Cafe Tandoor every Tuesday.
>
> We are going to The Winking Lizard to have **dinner**.

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck!

Comment: OH I can see now better

Comment: Good, I'm glad that I could be of assistance.